# How can I resolve the missing blocks inconsistency issue between 2 name nodes

Tags: hdfs, namenode

After performing decommission and recommission tasks, I encountered an issue with missing blocks, resulting in an inconsistency problem. In Ambari, I received a "Namenode Health" alert with the following details:

nn01: Total Blocks: 3,607,770, Missing Blocks: 0
nn02: Total Blocks: 3,607,770, Missing Blocks: 2,875

I'm looking for a solution to fix this problem.

Can you provide any guidance or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check if "all" the datanodes are connected to the other namenode as well, mostly some of them aren't, that is the reason for missing block on one namenode & no missing block on one